# Is it necessary to make members of custom classes parcelable in order to make the class parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String poster_path;
    private String overview;
    private String release_date;
    private String original_title;
    private String backdrop_path;
    private float vote_average;
    private Review review;
    private Trailer trailer

}
```

I have Movie class that have two other classes which are Review and Trailer.
Do I have to implements Parcelable to Review and Trailer as well ? or just root class need to implement parcelable ?

I am asking because If I do not have to do my code would be much shorter

Comment: you have to make them parcelable

Comment: Also please check this library called Parceler, it will make your code much shorter. Since you already know the concept of parcelable no harm in using the library.

Answer (score 0):

Each class you include in your Parcelable must implement Parcelable. You can see an example of how to parcel a Parcelable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923039/android-implementing-parcelable-inner-class/35923229#35923229)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must implement all additional method to make object Parcelable but you can try this [library](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) this will make your code simple and will do all job for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer `Movie`  objects between different Android components, then that should be `parcelable` and whatever  objects inside `Movie` class are not `serializeable/parcelable` , you need to make those also `parcelable`. Otherwise it will not work properly.